# how to display some message once user starts to compose new email

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

For Office 365 Outlook Web App, we would like to convert attachments to links once end user uploads them, however we didn't see an attachment notification event at current Outlook Addin.

Another approach we could do is to ask them to use our own buttons for uploading, however we need to guide end user to use our own buttons, could we add some message at top of email body like below once new email message box is displayed?
[image]

Somehow based on our research, Outlook Addin only has one event right now which is [SendEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins), could someone confirm this? if so, it is rather limited.

Answer (score 5):

To display a custom message use [`Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=office-js) object. For example to add a message to current item the code may looks like ...

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("information", {
    type: "informationalMessage",
    message : "My custom message.",
    icon : "iconid",
    persistent: false
});
```

Be aware there are a maximum of 5 notifications per message and maximum length of each message text is 150 characters per [`Office.NotificationMessageDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessagedetails?view=office-js) interface.

For the secondary question you would need to look at available events in [`Office.EventType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=office-js) enum. Over here you'll see few events available to Outlook app. One of them you are interested in is `AttachmentsChanged` which is currently available only in Preview (not released yet, but will be soon).

Comment: Thanks Slava (somehow I could not use @ anymore :-( ). we run into some issues on other events on itemChanged and RecipientsChanged,  just wonder if you used those before or not. As for GA plan of AttachmentsChanged, any rough idea? We are working on a project and it is a little time sensitive right now for us.

Comment: @windfly2006 Unfortunately, I don't have insider info on Microsoft release dates. There are a lot of Microsoft ppl over here, but most likely they would not provide with timeline as well. Anyway it will take few months, indeed. As for evens you have mentioned, I didn't use them, as they are quiet new (Mailbox 1.7 API level must be set in your manifest), but it should be straight forward. Please post another specific question, related to issues you are experience, someone definitely would help. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Slava. sure, we would open specific questions for those issues then.